# Mathematical Induction: Sum of first n odd perfect cubes

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

The series is $$P_k: 1^3 + 3^3 + 5^3 + ... + (2k-1)^3 = k^2(2k^2-1)$$ and I have to replace
$P_k$ with $P_{k+1}$ to prove the series.

I have to show that $$k^2(2k^2-1) + (2k-1)^3 = (k+1)^2[2(k+1)^2-1]$$ 
I'm sorry that I'm asking but their are just so many factors the algebra just passes over my 
head. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you need to show is **not**
$$k^2(2k^2-1) + (2k-1)^3 = (k+1)^2[2(k+1)^2-1].$$
What you need to show is 
$$k^2(2k^2-1) + (2(\color{red}{k+1})-1)^3 = (k+1)^2[2(k+1)^2-1].$$

And we can show this as the following : 
$$\begin{align}k^2(2k^2-1) + (2(k+1)-1)^3&=2k^4-k^2+(2k+1)^3\\&=2k^4-k^2+8k^3+12k^2+6k+1\\&=(2k^4+4k^3+2k^2)+(4k^3+8k^2+4k)+(k^2+2k+1)\\&=2k^2(k+1)^2+4k(k+1)^2+(k+1)^2\\&=(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1)\\&=(k+1)^2(2(k+1)^2-1).\end{align}$$

Comment: oh thank you so much i forgot to substitute k+1 for the last term, really appreciate it!!

Comment: @humzahkiani: Glad to help you. You are welcome.